# How to verify if the IP is replaced with proxy server(selenium, python)

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

How can I verify if the actual IP address is replaced by the proxy server. I attached the code. I made the program with selenium and python.

```html
# selenium imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import random

PROXY ="88.157.149.250:8080";


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
# //a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.amazon.com/')]/@href
LINKS_XPATH = '//*[contains(@id,"result")]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(
    'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_11444071011_nr_p_8_1/132-3636705-4291947?rh=n%3A3375251%2Cn%3A%213375301%2Cn%3A10971181011%2Cn%3A11444071011%2Cp_8%3A2229059011')
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(LINKS_XPATH)
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get a webpage like https://api.ipify.org?format=json

**OR**

You could also build your own service, that just prints out the source IP of the request...

```
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_my_ip", methods=["GET"])
def get_my_ip():
    return jsonify({'ip': request.remote_addr})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = False, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 80, threaded = True)
```

Comment: Clean and effective (+1)

Comment: Should I add this line of code: app = Flask(__name__)?

Comment: oh yes of course, I've edited my answer with what should be a fully running flask server, didn't test though, let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: I added Flask(to the first line to import) and it returns:  Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: yes, the server is running, now with your other script, you can use selenium to query your external IP address, through the proxy, and see what IP you get.

Answer (score 1):

Just visit a page that shows it like the one Loïc showed. Then after that, you go on to visit Amazon, or whatever website you want, knowing you are using the correct IP address.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get('https://api.ipify.org/')
ip_address = navigator.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").text
print(ip_address)
```

Comment: Any solution to get the PROXY IP address Binded with WebDriver ?